# How to run multiple scripts one after the other on a remote server after doing sshpass from by local server to the remote server?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, ssh

I ssh to the remote server directory using

```
sshpass ssh -t remote_server_name "cd /desired_directory/; exec $SHELL -l"
```

Now I want to run a few scripts inside that directory. I am trying using `./name.sh` after the above line but it's not working. Please help.

Comment: Combine them with `&&`?  Something like this `cd /desired_directory/ && bash name.sh` I use a lot

Comment: What if i want to run more than one script?

Comment: Double-quotes will evaluate the variable on the local machine. If this is not desirable, you may use single quotes or escape the variable `\$variable`.

Comment: *What if i want to run more than one script?* You can use logical and one more time: `cd /desired_directory/ && bash name.sh && bash name2.sh`. Note when using the operator `&&` if some of the scripts returns an error the next script wont be executed.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working". What are the error messages, if any? Why are you running `exec $SHELL -l`?